# What if someone changes name of HTML form inputs

Tags: html, forms, inspect-element

So I'm working on a website with various post forms, and I can't wrap my head around this: What if a user were to use inspect element to change the names of the html input tags so that my server-side application can't read the incoming data. Is there any way to prevent this or should I simply check whether the fields which I named myself do in fact exist and redirect the user in case my backend detects that the input forms have been tampered with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No actually there is no way to avoid client to change request. and clients can create custom request for a attack to your apis. you have to validate request in server.

Answer (score -1):

When someone change html code with insepct
And then click the submit button
All the code reset to defualt
Like refresh